# CSS need help at "formatting"

Tags: html, css

If we look at my [site](http://tekkkz.com/posts/articles/arch_installation.html), we see that the icon with the like and dislike button is not on its correct place. I want it to be to the right of the text `evaluate tekkkz.com` and above `XX total views`. So that's my html:

```
<div id="bar">
  <span>evaluate<br><a href="../../">tekkkz.com</a></span>
  <a class="icon-small" id="like"></a>
  <a class="icon-small" style="margin: 0 0" id="dislike"></a>
  <br>
  <span id="views"></span>
</div>
```

And here some CSS:

```
.icon-small {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    margin: 0 0.5em;
}
#bar span {
    float: none;
    padding: 0 0.2em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#bar {
    right: 70px;
    top: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 0.7em;
}
```

So what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote the HTML. Not all the changes are necessary to solve your issue, but I think it's better practice to makes your elements divs as opposed to spans with `<br />`. A hard-coded break like this makes it more complicated to control line breaks using CSS. I also found it easier to group your like/dislike buttons in one div.

```
<div id="bar">
  <div class="evaluate">evaluate<br><a href="../../">tekkkz.com</a></div>
  <div class="likeButtons">
      <a class="icon-small" id="like"></a>
      <a class="icon-small" style="margin: 0 0" id="dislike"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="views"></div>
</div>
```

Then for the CSS I used `inline-block` to put the necessary elements side by side.

```
.evaluate, .likeButtons { /* this is new */
    display: inline-block;
}
.icon-small {
    display: inline-block; /* was block before */
    /*position: absolute; <-- remove this */
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    margin: 0 0.5em;
}
/*#bar span {
    float: none;
    padding: 0 0.2em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
^ I don't think you need this any more,
maybe the padding but I'm sure you can work that out yourself */

#bar { /* didn't touch this */
    right: 70px;
    top: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 0.7em;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic work. So much time for my problem, writing so much fixes! Very good!

Answer (score 0):

You're positioning the icons absolutely, but not defining where they go (top, bottom, left, right) in the parent, which is also positioned absolutely.

You're probably going to need to define a top value for them both, then individually define a left or right value.

I would strongly recommend restructuring the html and use floats instead to accomplish what you want. Using absolute positioning can be a pain and very buggy.

Comment: absolute is necessary cause it should be a little bar between background and text in the padding of the box

Comment: Then you're going to need to use the positioning params to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Remove position: absolute;
seems to work